# Cache the password if SSH-keys are forbidden

Tags: ssh, git

I have a server which I have to access frequently via ssh, because I compute on it.
Now, the computing center *explicitly forbids* SSH-keys because they are "insecure". They feel that typing my password, on a keyboard, everytime, possible in front of other humans, is a much safer way to login.

Now; I cannot change their minds (I tried).

Is there a way to at least temporarily store SSH passwords, the way GIT can store passwords in a cache for some defined time?

Comment: `the computing center explicitly forbids SSH-keys because they are "insecure"` - my opinion on the matter? Find a new server host, because yours is obviously inept.

Comment: @Matt: "computing center" sounds more like an academic grid system, which doesn't have nearly as much competition I guess

Comment: They are wrong. They have probably been forgetting to disable ssh keys when they expire accounts, so they decided that ssh keys are the problem.

Comment: grawity is right. it's a national supercomputer so I'm stuck with it. for what it's worth, the machine is nice. Joshua is probably right as well, but, well, that's the kind of right not good for anything

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't support other authentication systems such as Kerberos or GSI (Globus) though? Both of these are fairly common and secure, and support credential persistence.

Comment: Does your department have a white-hat hacking team? Many companies have one of these, and they essentially test the company's security by launching real attacks and reporting the results. The data these guys get back could let you guys know whether SSH keys or passwords are more secure (and they could very easily swing in favor of the former by installing keyloggers).

Comment: @TheHansinator If there is a keylogger installed you have already been compromised to the point where it no longer matters whether you are protecting your ssh connections. But there are other advantages of `publickey` authentication. If you disable `password` authentication on the server, you prevent all of those attackers trying to guess passwords. And if an attacker attempt a mitm attack against a client which has not previously stored the public key of the server, you are much better protected with `publickey` than if you were using `password` authentication.

Comment: @kasperd Is there a reason you are using code block for emphasis? Not many screen readers read code blocks as emphasis, and just call call them out as "code" instead.

Comment: @Ferrybig I use code blocks because these are identifies with a very specific meaning to ssh. You can use those strings verbatim in an `ssh` command line or configuration file. I have no idea how a screen reader deals with any of the markup on StackExchange, and I do not feel qualified to have an opinion on how it should be treated. If it doesn't work in a sensible way I wouldn't even know if the screen reader or StackExchange is to blame. Further questions about that might be suitable for meta.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### Connection reuse

SSHv2 allows the same authenticated connection to establish multiple 'channels' – interactive shell, batch command, SFTP, along with the secondary ones such as agent-forwarding or TCP-forwarding. Your server probably supports connection multiplexing by default. (If your admins complain, it's not caching your password anywhere – it's caching the whole connection.)

With OpenSSH you have `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options (-M and -S) to make use of this:

1. Start a 'master' SSH connection using `-M`. (Since you don't have a ControlPath in your config yet, you need to specify it in command line using `-S`. It needs to live long, so I add the `-fN` options to drop to background; they're technically optional otherwise.)

   ```
   $ ssh foo@bar.example.com -fNMS ~/.ssh/bar.socket
   foo@bar.example.com's password:
   ```

   You're back to the local shell.
2. Start a new connection through the master:

   ```
   $ ssh foo@bar.example.com -S ~/.ssh/bar.socket
   ```

   You're in.
3. To make this useful for Git/rsync/SFTP, you need to set up `ControlPath` in your configuration, because you won't be able to specify `-S` all the time:

   ```
   Host *
       ControlPath ~/.ssh/S.%r@%h:%p
   ```

You can automate this – recent OpenSSH versions also have `ControlPersist` which automatically establishes a master connection in background if there isn't one yet. This allows you to skip step 1 and just use *ssh* as you normally would.

1. Configuration in `~/.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host *
       ControlPath ~/.ssh/S.%r@%h:%p
       ControlMaster auto
       ControlPersist 15m
   ```
2. First connection asks for password:

   ```
   $ ssh foo@bar.example.com
   foo@bar.example.com's password:
   [foo@bar:~]$ exit
   ```
3. The second doesn't:

   ```
   $ ssh foo@bar.example.com
   [foo@bar:~]$ yay
   ```

To control the multiplex master (stop it or configure TCP forwardings), use the `-O` option.

A similar method is supported by [recent PuTTY versions](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-sharing).

Comment: thank you very much for this nice answer.
google was not useful on this problem, as it always turned to ssh-keys and I did not know the right keywords. helped me a lot!

Comment: It should go without saying, but if you use this configuration is is imperative that you make sure your account is secured and that that your .ssh folder is correctly locked down as anyone with access to the channel files on that machine can piggyback off of your connection, and access the server as you.

Comment: @shellster: You mean "anyone with the same UID", just as is the case with ssh-agent already. Even if you deliberately open up the socket file's permissions (which are 0600 by default), other users will just get "multiplex uid mismatch" out of it.

Comment: @grawity Good additional information, but I think it is worth pointing out that a user like "root" is going to have the ability to hijack a UID or reset a password, thus giving them access to the socket with the correct UID.  Just because someone might be highly privileged locally doesn't mean they should also have the user's privileges on the remote server.

Comment: @shellster Someone with root could install a keylogger and steal your password to the remote system anyway, or do any number of nefarious things. If we're worried about local root, this is no less secure than saving an SSH private key.

Comment: I don't consider local root a threat because if it ever becomes a threat, you're toast no matter what. (As with government-grade spying.) Frankly a local root could just replace your ssh client _and_ ssh-agent with whatever they want. Store all passwords and private keys in /root/.secret? Sure.

Answer (score 19):

## Use `sshpass`

sshpass ([github](https://github.com/kevinburke/sshpass), [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass)) is a tool that automatically feeds the password to ssh. The secure way to use it is this:

```
% echo 'correct horse battery staple' > ~/.ssh/compute_password
% chmod go-rw ~/.ssh/compute_password

% sshpass -f ~/.ssh/compute_password ssh foo@host
```

This will read the password from `~/.ssh/compute_password`, much like a private key file without passphrase. You could put the `sshpass` command in a small shell script or a shell alias to avoid typing that full command. Sadly, I haven't found a way to do this from `~/.ssh/config`.

(It is also possible to specify the password directly on the command line to `sshpass`, but this should be avoided, as it leaks the password to anyone who can do `ps`)

### Comparison to other methods

This approach is of course less secure than properly set up public key authentication, but you probably know that already.

It is also less secure than @grawity's answer about connection re-use, but it has the advantage of not having to enter the password interactively at all.

You could consider @grawity's answer an alternative to pubkey auth with a passphrase and private key caching (i.e. `ssh-agent`). Then my answer would be an alternative to pubkey auth without a passphrase on the private key file.

Comment: If the computing centre's policy was written based on "but keypairs are stored on disk where someone could steal them!", then it looks like that policy is going to rather backfire.

Comment: @grawity Well, bad policies lead to even worse work-arounds ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If you generate your password as a sufficiently long stream of random characters (say `head -c 16 /dev/urandom | base64` for 128 bits) and don't use it on other systems, it's security-wise similar to a key. As hard to brute force, and as simple to use from the file if not encrypted. This goes for the bad guy too, if they get the file. The only difference is that the password is sent to the server as-is, while keys have better maths to prove that you own the correct private key without revealing it, and usability-wise, it's harder to encrypt the file containing the password (no standard tools).

Answer (score 1):

Use password manager.

Some password managers (ex. KeePassXC) have the 'auto-type' feature. You store the password on the password manager, unlock the database when you run the manager and every time `ssh` prompts you for your password you press a key combination which makes the password manager write your long password to the console.

No need to copy, remember anything (except for the password to unlock the database) and you can have a strong password without mashing those 30 characters every time you try to login.

You can pick your favourite from this list:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_password_managers

Comment: I'm not sure if the auto-type feature works well with terminal-based programs. The detection will be looking for a specific window title, and the autotyping itself best not have the fancy "anti-keylogging" features that KeePass2 had...

Comment: @grawity `gnome-terminal` changes its title to `ssh somehost` when ssh asks me for password so you can match the title window against this with no problems. I don't know anything about 'anti-keylogging' features - I'm using KeePassXC in terminal on daily basis and the worst I had to  deal with is choosing the appropriate account from the list.

Comment: @grawity The anti-keylogging features need to be enabled on a per-entry basis anyway (exactly for the reason that many programs do not support paste).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a GUI ssh client. On Windows the obvious choice would be [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). There's also a Linux version of PuTTY, notably most Debian based distros like Ubuntu normally include PuTTY in their repo.

Another really good client is [Termius](https://www.termius.com/). It supports not just Windows and Linux but also OSX, iOS and Android. Although it was primarily designed for phones the desktop version is actually quite good.

If I'm not mistaken, the venerable Hyperterminal on Windows also has/had an ssh client built in but I haven't used windows in a very long time so I'm not entirely certain.

All GUI clients include the ability to save connection settings which includes your username and password.

Comment: "GUI-based" doesn't automatically imply it'll allow storing your password, something which [PuTTY explicitly refuses to do](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/remember-password.html). The version of HyperTerminal that was bundled with Windows was Telnet-only, focused more on serial links. Maybe you're thinking of CKermit for Windows which does have SSH support, but its cipher support is so outdated it won't easily connect to many current servers.